# Getting 404 error for HTML links

Tags: html

I am having an issue on my website when trying to link a thumbnail of an image on my website to the full size image in a new window.  The website is live and being hosted on HostPapa so I'm not sure if my href needs to be changed to reflect this?  This is the HTML markup:

```
<a href="img/gallery/img4.jpg" alt="Image Alt"><img src="img/gallery/img4-thumb.png"></a>
```

**Folder structure is as follows:**

```
|-- public_html
|  |-- index.html
|  |-- css
|  |   |   |-- styles.css
|  |-- img
|  |   |   |-- gallery
|  |   |   |   |-- img3.jpg
|  |   |   |   |-- img3-thumb.png
|  |   |   |   |-- img4.jpg
|  |   |   |   |-- img4-thumb.png
```

When the image is clicked in the browser, I get this error:

**Not Found
The requested URL /img/gallery/img4.jpg was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.**

This worked fine when working offline on my local machine, but as soon as I put it online it stopped working as intended.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: We cannot say anything here, since we have no idea about your folder layout and site settings. We cannot look over your shoulders, you see?

Comment: does your server support/configured for case sensitivity for file/directory names? is img/gallery/img4.jpg the right exact name? Servers can be picky with path/file names, if your img4 is actually Img4, this is different for the server.

Comment: surgiie that was the issue, thank you! The actual file was a .JPG and I was trying to link to a .jpg file.  Why would this work offline, but not online?  I don't know much about the server side, but from what I have read I'm gathering that this is because the server is a UNIX platform which is case-sensitive, where as Windows platforms like my local machine are not.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<a href="/img/gallery/img4.jpg" alt="Image Alt"><img src="/img/gallery/img4-thumb.png"></a>
```

Or if you are using PHP:

```
<a href="<?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>/img/gallery/img4.jpg" alt="Image Alt">
 <img src="<?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>/img/gallery/img4-thumb.png">
</a>
```